# Conditional expectation of a linear combination of random variables given one of the random variables

Tags: probability, independence, conditional-expectation

I recently got confused by an expression I found in a paper,
$$E[aX + bY \mid Y]  = aE[X\mid Y] + bY, $$

I am confused that it's true if $X$ and $Y$ not independent. What would be the decomposition if any.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, what would $\mathbb E[X\mid \sigma(Y)]$ be?

Comment: This equation relies on two properties of conditional expectation: linearity and taking out what is known.  (The latter is applied here in the form $E[Y\mid Y]=Y.$) Which part of this might be the source of the confusion you refer to?

Comment: I got confused by the $bE(Y|Y) = Y$, I thought it should be $b$, but I understand it now thanks. Because $E(Y|Y=y) = y$, it would also be a random variable.